# WorkManager : "Error executing JobStatus" after closing app

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-workmanager

I'm trying to make WorkManager work.
When the application is open, my Worker is called and works fine. But if I close the app, Work seems to be called but doesn't work properly. When the Work is supposed to be called, this is repeatedly printed to Log many times with various interval (from .2s to ~3mn):

```
D/JobScheduler: Error executing JobStatus{77adc43 #u0a232/9 xyz.golshr.mypackage/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService u=0 s=10232 TIME=-8m0s826ms:none READY}
```

Here is the Work class :

```java
public class ApiTestWorker extends Worker {
    public ApiTestWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        MyLog.e(this, "Work woke up ! ID{" + this.getId() + "}, runAttempts:{" + this.getRunAttemptCount() + "}");
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Here is the work declaration on MainActivity :

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest saveRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ApiTestWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this)
                .enqueue(saveRequest);
    }
```

This is config for WorkManager inside my Application class :

```java
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return new Configuration.Builder().setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG).build();
    }
```

And this is my AndroidManifest :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xyz.golshr.mypackage">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is super-simplified version of my main application. So, there is no more code than that.
How can I make my Worker... work